# Regex for an anchor tag which contains a specific inline style

Tags: regex

Unfortunately my blog was hacked and 1000+ posts have been infected with links to spam sites. As part of the cleaning process I'm trying to use a regex to find and replace the bad links in an XML file in Sublime Text.

The only consistency I can see is all the bad links contain an inline style changing the text colour to #676c6c, so I'm trying but failing to create a regular expression that can highlight all anchor tags containing this hex value - #676c6c

```
<a[\s]+([^>]+)>((?:.(?!\<\/a\>))*.)</a>
```

So far I've got this, which I believe highlights all anchor tags, can anyone help expand this to include anchors containing #676c6c between the first angled brackets? Here's an example of one of the bad links

```
<a href="http://example-spam-url.net" style="text-decoration:none;color:#676c6c">spam keyword</a>
```

I appreciate any help! Cheers.

Comment: Wouldn't this give you what you expect : `<a.*?color:#676c6c.*?<\/a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use `<a[^>]+#676c6c[^>]+>[^<]*<\/a>`.

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/biPrIK/1).

If the anchor tag may contain other tags, use `(?s)<a[^>]+#676c6c[^>]+>.*?<\/a>` instead.